# Having trouble stacking all items using CSS grid

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stack all of my elements in my Rock Paper Scissors homepage, so that they eventually animate and appear one after another in this order: Rock, Paper, Scissors, Begin. I can get every element to stack on each other except for the "Begin". I have every piece on the same grid column and row, what am I doing wrong?

```css
* {
  font-size: 200px;
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: dark red;
  font-weight: 900;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
}

#title-rock {
  background: url(https://images.fineartamerica.com/images/artworkimages/mediumlarge/2/shiny-black-rocks-micha-pawlitzki.jpg);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

#title-paper {
  background: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/shoot-wrinkled-paper-texture-177335074.jpg);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

#title-scissors {
  background: url(https://images.freecreatives.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Scratched-Shiny-Metal-Plate-Texture.jpg);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

#begin {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title-text" id="title-rock">ROCK</h1>
<h1 class="title-text" id="title-paper">PAPER</h1>
<h1 class="title-text" id="title-scissors">SCISSORS</h1>
<h1 class="title-text"><a id="begin" href="game.html">BEGIN</a>
```

Comment: You have the anchor element with id begin and your try to place that in the grid. But it’s its parent that you need to place in the grid ie the element that is a direct child of the element with grid setting, like #Rock for example.

Comment: @AHaworth I tried doing the same to the h1 element, the parent of the a element, and still nothing happens.

Comment: Please could you put that code into your question so we can see why it doesn’t work

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, `<a>` is not a grid item in your example, because it is not a direct descendant of the grid.
Instead, you should apply grid item properties to its parent, `<h1>`, which is a grid item in this case.

```
 <h1 class="title-text"><a id="begin" href="game.html">BEGIN</a></h1>
```

> We create a grid container by declaring display: grid or display: inline-grid on an element. As soon as we do this, all direct children of that element become grid items.

The emphasis is on *direct* children. `<a>` is not a direct child of the grid container, but `<h1>` is.
You can learn more about basic grid concepts [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout#grid_container).

As you can see, there are 4 grid items in your case and they all have class `title-text`. To avoid repetition simply write

```
.title-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

You can now remove these properties elsewhere in your style.css (#title-rock, ... ).
Finally, move `background-color: darkred;` from `* {...}` to `body {...}`.

---

Additional notes:

To play with the 'depth' of the grid items (z-order to be precise), you can try adding `z-index` to `#title-rock` or any other item. You can read more about z-index [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).